# If something has a $12\%$ probability of occurring every decade, what is the probability that it will occur in $100$ years?

Tags: probability, statistics

If something has a $12\%$ probability of occurring every $10$ years, what is the probability that it will occur in $100$ years? And also in $150$ years?

Is the formula for this as simple as $1-{0.88}^{10}$ or is it more complicated?

Comment: Assuming independency and how I would interprete the formulation, it is in fact so simple

Comment: Why would it not be so simple?

Comment: @fleablood If an answer is so easy, we tend to search the trap (which doesn't exist)

Comment: Your answer would be right if the question would be like "What is the probability that it will occur **at least once** in 100 years"

Comment: @callculus I would interprete the formulation that way, but you are right that the formulation is not quite clear. And someone might interprete the first part as : "The probability that the event occurs in every decade is $12$%". I remember the debate about the famous game of the two goats and the car behind three doors. Is it an advantage to change the original decision ?

Comment: @peter I agree.

Comment: Hi there. Welcome to Math.SE. I'd recommend you to check this out for future helps regarding formatting.
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It depends on where you heard it.  Learning that if probability is $p$ then the probability in n occurrance is 1 - (1-p)^n isn't an "obvious" or "simple" result.  Once you learn it practicing to recognize it and apply it fairly is a standard exercise.  Later if you see it as something that must be done along the way to another result it need not be a trap any more than needing to add two integers would be.  But if it's a question on a quiz of tough math questions and all the others are harder... well, then yes.

Comment: The probability of "every 10 years"  is ambiguous.  It could be interpreted (by a lawyer) that that there is a 12% chance that it is such that event will occur like clockwork every 10 years and an 88% chance that it is a completely different type of event of which we have no idea.   Suppose you have have a sample of 100 seeds 12 of them are to a pant that blooms every ten years, 59 of them are sterile,  the rest ... who knows.

Comment: When you say "what is the probability that it will occur in 100 years" do you mean "occurs for the first time in a 100 year interval"?  If so your formula would be correct if for each decade the probability is independent of all past interval.

Comment: I should have said "occurs at least once in the past 100 years".

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is to regard such rare events as Poisson.

If the Poisson rate is $\lambda_{10}$ for a ten year period and $X_{10}$ is the number
of events that occur in ten years, then we have 
$$P(X_{10} \ge 1) = 1 - P(X_{10} = 0) = 1 - e^{-\lambda_{10}},$$
so that $e^{-\lambda_{10}} = 0.88$ and $\lambda_{10} = -\log_e (.88) =  0.1278.$

Then the rate for 100 years is $\lambda_{100} = 1.278.$ If $X_{100}$
is the number of events in 100 years, then 
$P(X_{100} = 0) = e^{-1.278} = 0.2786$ and $P(X_{100} \ge 1) = 0.7214.$

Of course, this is about the same as your $1 - .88^{10} = 0.7215,$  but you might find it interesting to think about the Poisson approach.

Answer (score -1):

**1 - 0.12^10 * 100 = 100 - 6.1917364E-8 %**

Try branching out the possibilities. in each branch multiply the percentage to get the odds of that branch happening.

Comment: Waaay out there on a very thin branch.

Comment: Check out @BruceET answer.

Comment: damn, I feel stupid